# change the color of the clicked pixel

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 app. There is a rectangle object in my app and in the Rectangle, I want to change the color of the pixel where user clicks. I have retrieved the pixel coordinates using the PointerPressed event of the rectangle(I retrieved the relative coordinates). My question is what function/method of the rectangle should I use to access the pixel properties so that I can change its color? Thanks

Comment: Why do you suppose there is any such function/method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do any of the 2 things.

1. Use Canvas instead of the Rectangle, in click handler create some shape object (e.g. ellipse or path), add that element to the Canvas' children, specifying correct position with `Canvas.SetTop` / `Canvas.SetLeft` static methods.
2. Fill your rectangle with an ImageBrush constructed from a WriteableBitmap, write pixel values in the WriteableBitmap.

If your user will only paint a few pixels, Canvas + shapes approach is more efficient. If you expect your user will paint many pixels, WriteableBitmap is better.

P.S. Don't forget there're devices out there with 1080×1920 px screens, such as Nokia Lumia Icon, Lumia 930, Lumia 1520, Samsung ATIV SE. Individual pixels will be invisible on those devices.